# Как проверить повторения в бд и выдать номер?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Пишу скрипт для бронирования номеров в гостинице. 
Есть две таблицы:

allnomer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75102 , где указаны все номера. В гостинице есть 3 номера lux: 301, 302 и 303.

И main http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02c4e , где указаны все брони.
Цель скрипта - проверять номера на занятость, и в случае нахождения свободного номера, выдаёт брони этот номер.

У меня есть дата заезда и дата выезда новой брони: 2016-11-28 и 2016-11-30. Это диапазон дат. То есть 28, 29 и 30 числа в гостинице собираются жить люди. В гостинице уже забронированы два номера. Первый (301) на даты с 2016-11-29 по 2016-12-01, второй (302) на даты с 2016-12-01 по 2016-12-02. Человек не может заехать в 301 номер, так как 29 и 30 числа этот номер будет занят. У нас остаётся два номера: 302 и 303. 302 номер занят только 01 и 02. Ни одна дата не пересекается и поэтому нам 302 номер подходит. Переменная $namenomer принимает значение 302 и подставляется в скрипт.

Подскажите, как сделать проверку на свободность номера, чтобы, в случае хотя бы одного совпадения, проверялся следующий номер? Вероятность того, что на этом этапе не найдётся ни одного свободного номера исключена. До этого этапа уже есть скрипт, который проверяет все номера на свободность. Однако он проверяет все номера. Этот же скрипт нужен для проверки определённых номеров.

Вот такой у меня сейчас код:

```
SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m ON
a.nomer = m.numbernomer AND (
m.datestart BETWEEN '2016-11-28' AND '2016-11-30' OR
m.dateend BETWEEN '2016-11-28' AND '2016-11-30' )
WHERE a.TYPE = 'lux' AND m.id IS NULL
```

И эти даты он обрабатывает правильно. Я получаю ответ 302.

Но если структура таблицы main вот такая sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fba1bd
, а запрос вот такой:

```
SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m ON
a.nomer = m.numbernomer AND (
m.datestart BETWEEN '2016-12-23' AND '2016-12-23' OR
m.dateend BETWEEN '2016-12-23' AND '2016-12-23' )
WHERE a.TYPE = 'lux' AND m.id IS NULL
```

То возвращается 301, хотя 23 число находится в диапазоне чисел таблицы main. 
Тоже самое со всеми числами, которые находятся в этом промежутке, кроме 19 и 25 числа.

Comment: А вы не правильно даты сравниваете. вы проверяете только дату начала или только дату окончания, а то что между ними вы не проверяете. если конкретный день - то `'2016-12-23' between datestart and dateend`. А интервал должен проверятся `datestart<='2016-11-30' and dateend>='2016-11-28'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @start = '2016-11-28';
SET @end = '2016-11-30';
SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m
  ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
  AND DATEDIFF(m.datestart, @end) * DATEDIFF(m.dateend, @start) <= 0
  -- AND a.type = 'lux'
WHERE m.numbernomer IS NULL
-- ORDER BY 1
-- LIMIT 1 
;
```

Если нужно строго неналожение (т.е. если бы номер освобождался 28-го или занимался 30-го, то он бы не подошёл), то заменить неравенство на строгое.

Comment: Зачем????? у тебя что, есть апартаменты разных категорий, но с одинаковыми номерами? Ну а даже если и есть... по логике запроса условие на x.type='lux' нужно добавлять в ON, а не во WHERE. А при левом связывании во WHERE проверять что-то из правой таблицы вообще нельзя - связывание немедленно превращается во внутреннее.

Comment: не то сказал.не numbernomer нужно сделать lux, а type сделать lux... Есть lux - это 301, 302 и 303 номер, есть vip - это 201 и 202 номер. Когда я выполняю твой запрос, мне возвращается 302,303,201,202. По сути, 201 и 202 я видеть не должен

Comment: Ну добавь в секцию ON условие AND a.type = 'lux'. **UPD:** Поправил в ответе.

Comment: да тупанул я. добавил сам, всё заработало. Через пару секунд приходит оповещение, что ты комментарий добавил. Спасибо!)

Comment: Стоп. А зачем в ON добавлять, когда можно сделать так: WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL ?

Comment: Можно. В данном случае это практически не играет роли - более того, планировщик может построить для обеих версий один и тот же план. Но логика требует сперва взять только люксы, а потом уже  смотреть, какие из них подходят, а не наоборот - значит, условие помещаем в предотбор. А на бытовом уровне - кажется, что серверу меньше считать, ибо он не станет считать значение выражения из WHERE для не-люксов.

Comment: @Akina А зачем такая странная логика с datediff. Обычное пересечение интервалов (которое я писал в комментариях к вопросу) аналогично по действию, только в отличие от datediff потенциально может работать по индексу. ну и более понятно, чем данные вычисления

Comment: @Mike А фиг знает... да, поскольку нужно НЕпересечение, достаточно 2 сравнений, объединённых OR. Или, чтобы уйти от OR (не каждая версия может его правильно оптимизировать), 2 отдельных запроса и UNION.